# SSRS Report very slow after doing inner join in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

First I used a query without the second select statement, the positive was that the report was really fast if I choose a long time period, but it displayed me every weekends and holidays. That was not a big issue, then I excluded every free days with the filter option in SSRS, after this the report showed me only the workdays, but the problem was, there were additional rows with a 0 and this affected the calculations.

The only solution was to add a second select statement "Scheduled".
After I added an inner join the report runs very slow. The second Select Statement is a schedule and it excludes all the weekends and holidays, and this does not display any extra row if I run it. But the big **Problem** is, that the report runs really slow. And If I choose over a period of six month it displays me a "Timeout Error".
The query:

```
SELECT c.date, 
       c.team, 
       c.NAME, 
       c.prod, 
       c.product 
FROM   (SELECT intervaldate AS Date, 
               tsystem.NAME AS NAME, 
               productname  AS Product, 
               teamname     AS Team, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN countername = 'Prod' THEN displayunits 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)     AS Prod 
        FROM   count 
               INNER JOIN tsystem 
                       ON count.systemid = tsystem.id 
        WHERE  intervaldate >= @StartDateTime 
               AND intervaldate <= @EndDateTime 
               AND tsystem.id IN (SELECT systemid 
                                  FROM   viewsystem 
                                  WHERE  viewid = 122) 
        GROUP  BY intervaldate, 
                  teamname, 
                  tsystem.NAME, 
                  productname) c 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT sh.scheduled AS Scheduled, 
                          sc.NAME      AS NAME 
                   FROM   history sh 
                          INNER JOIN schedule sc 
                                  ON ( sc.id = sh.scheduleid ) 
                   WHERE  scheduled != 0) p 
               ON p.NAME = c.NAME
```

Is there any possibility to make it faster?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? You can add the new `INNER JOIN` to the first query by JOINING it to `tsystem.NAME` and see if that helps? Can you share the query plan?

Comment: Based on what you're provided, I'd suggest (like @NickyvV) to look at the query plan. If you're not interested where "countername" is not "Prod" then perhaps that could be filtered out. Also I'd be tempted to replace the IN clause for "systemid" with an inner join and observe performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace below part of query (sub query) with join

**->  and tsystem.ID in (Select SystemID from ViewSystem where ViewID = 122)**

**-> Inner JOIN ViewSystem on tsystem.ID=ViewSystem.SystemID where ViewID=122**

Joins are way more faster than sub queries.